# SSIS Execute Package Task variable path

Tags: ssis

In SSIS 2008 I have 2 packages (package1 and package2) . I need call the package1 from package2, but the path changes on other servers . How I can set the path using variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically set the location of an Execute Package Task in SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370830/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-location-of-an-execute-package-task-in-ssis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Environment Variables to set the path for each environment, this links to SSIS Package Configuration which should be enabled.